# "Beet" als Ersatz für "Sträußchen"?

Tags: meaning

Das Beet hatte ich bisher nur als jenen Teil des Gartens verstanden, auf dem Gemüse/Pflanzen angepflanzt werden. Auch [der Duden verweist](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beet) bspw. nur noch auf die gemeinsame Herkunft von Beet und Bett, aber nennt keine wirklich darüber hinausgehende Nebenbedeutung.

Nun entdeckte ich heute aber in einem Rezept "1 Beet Kresse" als Zutat. Wobei kein Artikel oder eine eindeutige Beugungsform gegeben ist, um zu sagen welches grammatikalische Geschlecht dem Wort zugewiesen ist. Ich bleibe daher im Folgenden bei "das Beet".

Als Maßeinheit scheint mir "Beet" ungeeignet. Es gibt schließlich unterschiedlich breite und lange Beete und auch die Dichte der Bepflanzung würde eine Rolle spielen für die geerntete Menge. Wobei selbst der oben verlinkte Artikel im Duden zumindest folgendes Beispiel gibt:

> ein Beet Kohlrabi (die auf einem Beet wachsende Menge) anpflanzen

Ich vermute mal, daß es sich bei "1 Beet Kresse" nicht um die Menge Kresse von einem ganzen abgeernteten Beet unbekannter, weil nicht gegebener, Größe handelt, sondern wohl um ein Sträußchen Kresse?!

Nun meine Fragen:

1. Habe ich die Bedeutung korrekt erfaßt oder handelt es sich gar um eine alte, mir nicht geläufige, Maßeinheit? (Viele kennen heute ja auch nicht mehr [Gros und Schock](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alte_Ma%C3%9Fe_und_Gewichte_(deutschsprachiger_Raum)&oldid=162247229#Z.C3.A4hlma.C3.9Fe).)
2. Handelt es sich um eine regionale Eigenheit? Das Rezept stammt aus Südhessen, soweit ich das beurteilen kann.

Comment: Da ich die Mengenangabe noch nie gehört habe, habe ich sie einfach einmal gegoogelt. Und siehe da, diese Mengenangabe findet sich in sehr vielen Rezepten.

Comment: Die Anwendung dürfte spezifisch für Kresse sein, weil man die grundsätzlich und traditionell nicht im *Garten*beet, sondern immer in einem speziellen Behältnis (i.e. "Beet") von überschaubarer Größe anpflanzt.

Comment: @tofro: also wäre die Menge aus einem Pflanztopf/Töpfchen damit gemeint? Zumindest in den Teilen meiner Familie in denen es einen Garten gibt, wird Kresse im Garten angepflanzt. Wobei mir gerade auffällt, daß Kresse auch nicht eindeutig ist (Gartenkresse, Brunnenkresse).

Comment: Die Dinger aus dem Supermarkt sehen [so](http://www.supermarktcheck.de/product/75934-kresse) (erster Google-Fund, leider unscharf). Diese Menge ist "ein Beet".

Comment: Ja, natürlich - "Ein Beet Kartoffeln" habe ich noch in keinem Kochrezept gefunden ;) Und Gartenkresse (Das, was man im Supermarkt in der Schachtel kaufen kann und was man als Sämling ißt) bauen nur sehr geduldige Menschen oder Leute, die das Knirschen zwischen den Zähnen mögen, draußen an. Deine Überschrift passt übrigens auch nicht richtig - Ein "Sträußchen" aus Gartenkresse zu machen, gelingt nur bei der ausgewachsenen Pflanze (die man i.A. nicht mehr ißt), oder sehr detailverliebten Menschen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das *Beet* ist für Kresse eine durchaus übliche Handelsgröße. Es sieht ungefähr so aus:

[image]

Du kannst in den Supermarkt gehen und fünf Beete Kresse kaufen, oder du kannst ein Beet Kresse gemeinsam mit anderen Zutaten zu einem leckeren Brotaufstrich verarbeiten.

Answer (score 4):

Ich vermute, *Beet* wird hier als Synonym für *Keimschale* verwendet. Ich weiß nicht, ob es hierfür eine festgeschriebene Handelsnorm gibt, aber in der Regel sind käufliche Sprossen und Kresse in einer Schalengröße von ca. 20 cm Länge und 10 cm Breite erhältlich.

Ein **Beet** / Ein Schälchen enstpräche dann ungefähr **3 - 4 Kressesträußchen**.

Comment: Kresse hab ich noch nie irgendwo als Sträußchen gesehen. Geht das überhaupt? (siehe Kommentar von @torfro)

Comment: @Iris Ich habe inzwischen gelernt, dass ein *Kressesträußchen* in der gehobenen Gastronomie soviel Kresse ist, wie man mit 3 Fingern als Garnitur auf was Teures zum drunter Verstecken draufsetzt ;) . Mit einem Sträußchen im Sinne von "Bündel" hat das allerdings nicht zu tun.